# How can I know file size in grocery crud?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file, callback, grocery-crud

I need to know what it is the size of a file that I save in a folder with Grocery CRUD. This is what I did in  my controller:

```
$this->load->config('grocery_crud');
   $this->config->set_item('grocery_crud_file_upload_allow_file_types', 'pdf|rar|');
$this->crud->set_field_upload('fichero', 'assets/files'); 

 $this->crud->callback_after_insert(array($this, 'file_size'));
```

and the other method

```
function file_size($post_array, $primary_key) {
    if ($primary_key == $post_array['id']) {
            $nombre_db = $post_array['fichero'];
            $nombre_fichero = 'assets/files'. $nombre_db;
            $filesize = filesize($nombre_fichero);
        }
        echo $filesize;
```

my file is inside diferents folder, I do not know if this is a problem, I made an `echo $filesize` to see the value but do not show anithing, not  a value, not an error. Please help, thanks in advance.

**[Additional Information]**

The callback do not enter in the method, I put inside  **`function file_size`** an `echo` to see if show something or enter inside, but nothing, I do not know what its wrong with my callback funtion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, I was trying to solve it the wrong way, instead of making a callback, what I had to do was in the function that showed me all the results and then send them to the view, call a function that calculated the File size.

I leave my answer and the link from where I got it.

```
$url_file_update = 'assets/';
$file_name = $url_file_update . $query->row($i)->file; // file name
$weight_file = filesize($file_name); // we get the weight in bytes 
$file_size = $this->file_size($weight_file);  //  show the modified weight
```

the function **file_size**

```
function file_size($peso) {
  $decimales = 2;
  $clase = array(" Bytes", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB");
  return round($peso / pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($peso, 1024)))), $decimales) . $clase[$i];
}
```

[link to the documentation that I found](http://www.leonpurpura.com/tutoriales/calcular-peso-archivo.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to turn error reporting on.

You are (probably) missing slash in your file path:

```
$nombre_fichero = 'assets/files/'. $nombre_db;
```

But without error I am just guessing.

Comment: the problem is that it does not even go to the function. I put an echo and nothing

Comment: How should we know, that it does not even go to that line? You did not say that before (and that's yours part you have to do before asking).

Comment: It is my mistake don't put it in my question, I have another callback methods and they work OK, I put an echo inside them for see what is what they shows, thats why I make this question, asking for help, becouse I do not know what I am doing wrong